# remember after refresh selected row in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, grid, refresh, row, selection

I have a problem. I use extjs `grid`. This grid will be refreshed every `seconds`.

I refresh with this function:

```
ND.refresh = function() {
    ND.commList.load();
}


var refreshSeconds = refreshRate * 1000;
var t = setInterval('ND.refresh()', refreshSeconds);
```

But when someone selected a row to highlight it it `reset` this selection. 
How can I remember the selected row and highlight it again after refresh?

This is my grid:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
     autoscroll: true,
     region: 'center',
     store: ND.dashBoardDataStore,
     stateful: true,
     forceFit: true,
     loadMask: false,
     stateId: 'stateGrid',

     viewConfig: {
         stripeRows: true
     },
     columns: [{
         text: 'Vehicle',
         sortable: true,
         flexible: 1,
         width: 60,
         dataIndex: 'vehicle'
     }, {
         text: 'CCU',
         sortable: true,
         flexible: 0,
         width: 50,
         renderer: status,
         dataIndex: 'ccuStatus'
     }]
 });
```

Thanks guys

Comment: What version of Ext do you use? Test code (in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) would be nice so we have a starting point to help you in a best possible way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use EXT 4.0.2.
i don't know fiddle. How do i need to put it in there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote simple [Ext.grid.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) extension that automatically selects back rows that were selected before store reload. You can try it in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgoran/A2H5r/)

```
Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selectedRecords: [],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.getStore().on('beforeload', this.rememberSelection, this);
        this.getView().on('refresh', this.refreshSelection, this);
    },
    rememberSelection: function(selModel, selectedRecords) {
        if (!this.rendered || Ext.isEmpty(this.el)) {
            return;
        }

        this.selectedRecords = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        this.getView().saveScrollState();
    },
    refreshSelection: function() {
        if (0 >= this.selectedRecords.length) {
            return;
        }

        var newRecordsToSelect = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            record = this.getStore().getById(this.selectedRecords[i].getId());
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
                newRecordsToSelect.push(record);
            }
        }

        this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
        Ext.defer(this.setScrollTop, 30, this, [this.getView().scrollState.top]);
    }
});
```

Comment: hey looking good. I have only two issues. In firefox i get this error: this.selectedRecords[i].getId is not a function.
When i use it in chrome it will always select the first row after refresh. Any idea what that could be?

THANKS for the help :)

Comment: the error in firefox is fixed. But it is still going to the first row

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZemWB/ is where i placed my grid with your code. Can you see what is wrong with it?

Comment: First of all in that jsFiddle you created `ND` is undefined. I guess you copy/paste code from your project but it is not runnable. I guess you could have issues if you haven't set `idProperty` in your model (look at [my test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgoran/A2H5r/))

Comment: You are my hero! I didn't had a idProperty in my model. Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: I have no another issue :) I got a list higher then the screen, if i scroll down, select a row the row will stay selected but after refresh it scrolls back up. Can i do something about that?

Comment: Well you could try something with [Ext.view.Table.saveScrollState](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-saveScrollState) method and [Ext.grid.Panel.setScrollTop](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-setScrollTop) method. You can fetch view object of a grid panel with [Ext.grid.Panel.getView](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getView) method. Of course use appropriate methods in `rememberSelection` and `refreshSelection` methods of a custom extension.

Comment: I updated code in answer, so now panel set vertical scroll to its previous value. You can play with solution in that fiddle.

Comment: hey Sbgoran. There is an issue what i can't fix. When the page loads i get an error this.el is undefined and isn't loading the store. When the refresh function start it loads the store. I tried to remove this code and store loads fine. Do you have an idea what this.el could be?

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong in your code, but I added a check in `rememberSelection` that shouldn't do any harm, try it out, it might help.

Comment: This is great but it should be a plugin, not a base class!

Comment: @JuanMendes You are probably right, but I guess that answer shows the main idea for solution to a problem it should not be very hard to make plugin out of this. Maybe I'll do it when I get a chance, should be fun thing to do :)

Comment: @comecme It was a while ago, so if I remember well reason lays in a way Ext grid render its view, I think that they used defer call during grid panel rendering inside library itself, so if you call `setScrollTop` immediately, you'll get some sort of "null variable" or "non existent DOM element" error. It could be that later versions of Ext removed this and that it is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 7):

The straightforward solution is just save somewhere in js index of selected row. Then after reload you could easily select this row by index using grid's selection model.

Get selection model: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getSelectionModel

```
var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel()
```

Get selected rows: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection

```
var selection = selectionModel.getSelection()
```

Set selected row back: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select

```
selectionModel.select(selection)
```

Comment: i think i do something wrong because it isnt working. i use a listener:
itemclick: function () {
var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
var selection = selectionModel.getSelection();
selectionModel.select(selection);
var data = grid.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data;
  ND.internals.load({
                    url: ND.url 
                });

Comment: you should restore selection after your reloading is completed. So it's a good idea call selectionModel.select in grid's store load event.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to select the previously selected record:

```
var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel()

// get the selected record
var selectedRecord = selectionModel.getSelection()[0]

// get the index of the selected record
var selectedIdx = grid.store.indexOfId(selectedRecord.data.id);

// select by index
grid.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIdx);
```

For some reason the grid.getSelectionModel().select(record) method wasn't working for me, but selecting by index seems to work.

Edit: found out why grid.getSelectionModel().select(record) method wasn't working. Apparently the store is reloaded, the record instances aren't the same (they have different automatically generated Ext IDs). You have to use selectAt() in this case.

Comment: `#{GridPanel-ID}.getSelectionModel().select(index, true);` Works good for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

for extjs 4.1.7 users

need a workarround about the statement in

> refreshSelection() {
>
> > ...
> >        Ext.defer(this.setScrollTop, 30, this,
> >     [this.getView().scrollState.top])
>
> }

thus setScrollTop no longer exists

so a working soluction is add 
me.getView().preserveScrollOnRefresh = true;

in initComponent

```
Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selectedRecords: [],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.getStore().on('beforeload', this.rememberSelection, this);
        this.getView().on('refresh', this.refreshSelection, this);

        //-------------------------------------------
        me.getView().preserveScrollOnRefresh = true;
        //-------------------------------------------
    },
    rememberSelection: function(selModel, selectedRecords) {
        if (!this.rendered || Ext.isEmpty(this.el)) {
            return;
        }

        this.selectedRecords = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        this.getView().saveScrollState();
    },
    refreshSelection: function() {
        if (0 >= this.selectedRecords.length) {
            return;
        }

        var newRecordsToSelect = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            record = this.getStore().getById(this.selectedRecords[i].getId());
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
                newRecordsToSelect.push(record);
            }
        }

        this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your initComponent you try to use "me" without defining it.

Answer (score 0):

i have make modification on this code.
If you make selection, and aplys a filter on the store and reload it, the selection model have a first empty array in this selected collection ( at index 0 ).

This modification is in the last line of the "refreshSelection" function.

```
if (newRecordsToSelect.length >= 1){
        this.getSelectionModel().select(newRecordsToSelect);
        Ext.defer(this.setScrollTop, 30, this, [this.getView().scrollState.top]);
    }
```