# Go back to the selection in Data Grid after reloading the page ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remember after refresh selected row in extjs grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111084/remember-after-refresh-selected-row-in-extjs-grid)

I have a Data Grid in ExtJS 4.1. When I click on any cell(cell value behaves as a url to another page), I will be landed on a different page with a new Data Grid. Now I need to get back to same selection on the Grid when I click on the back button on the browser.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri