# How to Re-selecting row after store.load()

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have grid panel and a button.
**when** i click button it will transfer data via ajax and **after** finish grid will reload.

I try to re-selected row (in here i give u example is first row), but anyway it's not working

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: ...,
    params: {
        v: ...                  
    },
    success: function(response){
        grid.store.load();                                            
        grid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true); // example first row

    }
})
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9111084/539048

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try selecting row in callback

```
grid.store.load({
  scope:this,
  callback:function(records, operation, success){
     grid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true); 
  }
});
```

or

```
grid.store.load(function(records, operation, success){
  grid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your row selections survive across store reloads by applying the following overrides:

```
Ext.override(Ext.view.View, {
    preserveSelectionOnRefresh: true,
    constructor: function() {
        this.callOverridden(arguments);
        if (this.preserveSelectionOnRefresh) {
            this.mon(this.getStore(), {
                beforeload: this.beforeStoreLoadPreserveSelectionRoutine,
                scope: this
            });
        }
    },
    beforeStoreLoadPreserveSelectionRoutine: function() {
        var sm = this.getSelectionModel(),
            selection = sm.getSelection(),
            i = 0,
            l = selection.length,
            savedSelection = [];
        delete sm.savedSelection;
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            savedSelection.push(selection[i].getId());
        }
        if (savedSelection.length) {
            sm.savedSelection = savedSelection;
        }
    }
});
Ext.override(Ext.selection.Model, {
    refresh: function() {
        // include selections saved across store reloads        
        if (this.savedSelection && this.savedSelection.length) {
            var rs = [],
                r,
                j = 0,
                l = this.savedSelection.length;
            for (; j < l; j++) {
                r = this.store.getById(this.savedSelection[j]);
                if (r) {
                    rs.push(r);
                }
            }
            if (rs.length) {
                this.select(rs, false, true);
            }
        }
        this.callOverridden();
        delete this.savedSelection;
    }
});
```

What they do is just saving what was selected before reloading the store and ensuring those records are selected again after the view is refreshed. Tested on Ext JS 4.1.2.

Comment: Actually in Ext4 it was possible to simply do `var savedRecords = selModel.getSelection()` and then simply use `selModel.select(savedRecords)`... But since Ext 5 or 6 you need to re-get all records from store (as in above override) before selecting them. So your solution is more forward-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

... and if you are using a buffered store and Ext JS 4.2+, you could use the scrollTo function, which selects AND scrolls the view to your selection:

```
grid.store.load(function(records, operation, success){
  grid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(0, true);
});
```

Comment: the 4.2 scrollTo takes over the responsibility to load pages if they are not in the PageMap of the store. I think there is no such feature in 4.1, so you would have to load pages by your own.

Answer (score 2):

select row after loading the store by adding a callback:

```
grid.store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
    grid.getView().select(0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

grid.store.load ==> grid.store.on

http://bit.ly/1iBwb2i

Answer (score 0):

On response, maybe you can use a field to differentiate it :

Sencha 4.0.7: [store finde](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find)

```
store.find(fieldName, value);
```

Another way, but I think it isn't work after load store, it's use:

Sencha: [getLastSelected](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getLastSelected)

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected()
```

Comment: thanks u but it's not working for me. @MMT's answer working :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin the takes care of that for you:

https://github.com/roberto-rodriguez/ExtJs_GridMultipageSelectionPlugin

The plugin keeps the selection across the pages in the pagination grid. Also includes a function named: getSelection() to the grid, which returns the an array with the ids of the selected rows.

[image]

The plugin assumes there is a column with dataIndex: 'id'

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to select whatever was last selected (not just the first row as shown in the accepted answer) this is the simplest I think:

```
grid.store.load(function() {
    var view = grid.getView(),
        selModel = grid.getSelectionModel(),
        lastSelected = selModel.getLastSelected();

    view.select(lastSelected);
});
```

or better, a listener for all loading done by the store in the future:

```
grid.store.on('load', function() {
    var view = grid.getView(),
        selModel = grid.getSelectionModel(),
        lastSelected = selModel.getLastSelected();

    view.select(lastSelected);
});

grid.store.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue on Sencha 5.0.1. We found out this can be solved by adding an [idProperty](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty) to your model. After that you can just call the [reload()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.data.ProxyStore.html#method-reload) function on the store.

In your model:

```
idProperty: 'yourIdentifyingProperty',
```

Then

```
yourGrid.getStore().reload();
```

I'm not sure if you also have to bind the selection of the grid, but if the above doesn't work you could also try that.